My python code doesn't work on mac and I don't know why
I have built a personal assistant using python, and I got it to work on windows 10. I used this video tutorial. The code works on my windows 10 computer, but now that I ported it to MacOS it has stopped functioning. I have installed the following modules using the pip3 install command on my mac:

speechrecognition

pyttsx3

wikipedia

wolframalpha

spotipy


When on windows I used pip install but this didn't work so I used pip3 instead. Whenever I run my code I get the following error:
griffery@Tobiass-MacBook-Air Coding % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/griffery/Desktop/Personal/Coding/Harvey/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/griffery/Desktop/Personal/Coding/Harvey/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 12, in <module>
    class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 13, in NSSpeechDriver
    @objc.python_method
     ^^^^
NameError: name 'objc' is not defined. Did you mean: 'object'?

For reference my code is:
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyttsx3
import webbrowser
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha
import json
import spotipy



#Speech Init
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id) #0, male / 1, female
activationword = 'harvey' #should be single word

#Browser Config
chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))

#Wolfram AppId
appId = 'W85WJ8-UJLGGULT7R'
wolframClient = wolframalpha.Client(appId)

#Spotify App Id + Auth
username = 'j3ivta6qjh3p3haiuinv3aew8'
clientID = '5b61f8e1e290472e80b67d58fa41dfa3'
clientSecret = '35ceac9967104e82aa1a2e8e421c7f5d'
redirectURI = 'http://google.com/'

oauth_object = spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(clientID,clientSecret,redirectURI)
token_dict = oauth_object.get_access_token()
token = token_dict['access_token']
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
user = spotifyObject.current_user()
# To print the response in readable format.
print(json.dumps(user,sort_keys=True, indent=4))

#Functions
def speak(text, rate = 120):
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def ParseCommand():
    listener = sr.Recognizer()
    print('Listening for a command')
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source: #uses computer default mic
        listener.pause_threshold = 2
        input_speech = listener.listen(source)
    
    try:
        print("Understanding...")
        query = listener.recognize_google(input_speech, language='en_us')
        print(f'The input speech was: {query}')

    except Exception as exception:
        print("Excuse me?") 
        print(exception)
        return 'None'
    
    return query

def search_wikipedia(query = ''):
    searchResults = wikipedia.search(query)
    if not searchResults:
        speak('Error 404, page not found')
        return 'No result received'
    try:
        wikiPage = wikipedia.page(searchResults[0])
    except wikipedia.DisambiguationError as error:
        wikiPage = wikipedia.page(error.options[0])
    print(wikiPage.title)
    wikiSummary = str(wikiPage.summary)
    return wikiSummary

def listOeDict(var):
    if isinstance(var, list):
        return var[0]['plaintext']
    else:
        return var['plaintext']


def search_wolframAlpha(query = ''):
    response = wolframClient.query(query)

    # @success: Wolfram Alpha was able to resolve the query
    # @numpods: Number of results returned
    # pod: List of results. This can also contain subpods
    if response['@success'] == 'false':
        return 'Could not compute'
    
    #Query resolved
    else:
        result = ''
        #question
        pod0 = response['pod'][0]

        pod1 = response['pod'][1]
        # May contain the answer, has the highest confidence value
        # if it's primary, or has the title of result or definition, then it's the official result
        if (('result') in pod1['@title'].lower()) or (pod1.get('@primary', 'false') == 'true') or ('definition' in pod1['@title'].lower()):
            #get the result
            result = listOeDict(pod1['subpod'])
            #remove brackets
            return result.split('(')[0]
        else:
            question = listOeDict(pod0['subpod'])
            #remove brackets
            return result.split('(')[0]
            #search wikipedia instead
            speak('computation failed. Querying the universal databank instead')
            return search_wikipedia(question)

#Spotify
#Spotify search
def sp_search(query = ''):
    # Logic for search functionality
    # Get the Song Name.
    searchQuery = query
    # Search for the Song.
    searchResults = spotifyObject.search(searchQuery,1,0,"track")
    # Get required data from JSON response.
    tracks_dict = searchResults['tracks']
    tracks_items = tracks_dict['items']
    song = tracks_items[0]['external_urls']['spotify']
    # Open the Song in Web Browser
    webbrowser.open(song)
    
    


# Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    speak('All systems nominal.')

    while True:
        #Parse as a list
        query = ParseCommand().lower().split()

        if query[0] == activationword:
            query.pop(0)

            #list commands
            if query[0] == 'say':
                if 'hello' in query:
                    speak('Hello Sire, What can I do for you today')

                else:
                    query.pop(0) #Removes say from the list
                    speech = ''.join(query)
                    speak(speech)

            #go to specific site
            if query[0] == 'go' and query[1] == 'to':
                speak('opening...')
                query = ' '.join(query[2:])
                webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new(query)
            
            # Look up on goolge
            if query[0] == 'look' and query[1] == 'up':
                speak('searching')
                query = ' '.join(query[2:])
                question = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query
                webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new(question)
            
            #wikipedia
            if query[0] == 'wikipedia':
                query = ' '.join(query[1:])
                speak('Querying the universal databank.')
                result = search_wikipedia(query)
                speak(result)

            #Wolfram alpha
            if query[0] == 'compute' or query[0] == 'computer' or query[0] == "what's":
                query = ' '.join(query[1:])
                speak('Computing')
                try:
                    result = search_wolframAlpha(query)
                    speak(result)
                except:
                    speak('Unable to compute')
            
            #spotify 
            if query[0] == 'spotify' or query[0] == 'play':
                #search track
                if query[1] == 'search':
                    query = ' '.join(query[2:])
                    speak('Browsing spotify')
                    sp_search(query)
                elif query[1] == 'goat' and query[2] == 'search':
                    query = 'boywithuke', ' '.join(query[3:])
                    query = ' '.join(query)
                    speak('Searching for Boy with Uke')
                    sp_search(query)
                elif query[1] == 'play':
                    spotipy.start_playback()
                elif query[1] == 'pause' or query[1] == 'stop':
                    spotipy.pause_playback()
                elif query[1] == 'shuffle':
                    spotipy.shuffle()
                
                
        if 'power' and 'off' in query:
            speak('Goodbye Sire')
            exit()

I have tried reinstalling python but it still doesn't function. Thank you very much for helping me get my assistant back.

This question is similar to: Error running pyttsx3 code on OS X: "NameError: name 'objc' is not defined". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
